# Traceback (most recent call last): error on Anaconda launching

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to launch Application on Anaconda, but I have this application launch error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\emanu\anaconda3\Scripts\jupyter-notebook-script.py", line 6, in 
from notebook.notebookapp import main

File "C:\Users\emanu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\__init__.py", line 27, in 
from .nbextensions import install_nbextension

File "C:\Users\emanu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\nbextensions.py", line 26, in 
from .config_manager import BaseJSONConfigManager

File "C:\Users\emanu\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\config_manager.py", line 14, in 
from traitlets.config import LoggingConfigurable

File "C:\Users\emanu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\traitlets\__init__.py", line 1, in 
from .traitlets import *

File "C:\Users\emanu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 61, in 
from .utils.sentinel import Sentinel

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'traitlets.utils.sentinel'
```

I already update the PIP, but nothing works. How to solve?

Comment: What did you update in pip?  The "Sentinel" stuff is new in traitlets 5.0.

Comment: I did pip install --upgrade pip (version 21)

Comment: How is that possibly going to help?  The problem is your version of traitlets.  Did you do "pip install --upgrade traitlets`?